# How to test whether expression is a temporary?

Tags: c++, c++11, static-assert

With the following macro:

```
#define ASSERT_IF_TEMP(expr) static_assert(?, "Is temporary!");
```

What should I put for question mark?

Comment: The result of an expression is always a temporary.

Comment: @Clinton: Can you elaborate why you want to do this?

Comment: @Neil: Nonsense. If I have a `char* ptr = some_pointer();`, then the expression `*ptr` is an lvalue.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth For some definition of temporary.  From a practical point of view, temporary corresponds to what the standard calls an rvalue, and the result of some expressions are lvalues.

Comment: you could assert that something is temporary if in the stack (esp + offset) and not the heap ?

Comment: @Julio: wouldn't be an accurate assertion though - many temporaries will only exist in registers and never appear on the stack...

Comment: @Julio: That's really not good. For a start, that is totally not defined behaviour.

Comment: @Clinton - Please see the edit to my answer - my solution does not seem to differ from the one you said does not work!

Comment: @JohannesD: You're quite correct, I've edited my question to remove my claim that it doesn't work. Thanks for the answer, and sorry for the confusion, I'm not sure how I mucked this up.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First we should clarify: What do you mean by "temporary"?

Many people mean different things when they say temporary. Technically, `int()` is not a temporary, but most people will include them into their own meaning of that term. Technically, given `std::string s;`, then `move(s)` isn't a temporary either, but you may want to treat it as one with your macro.

The first kind of "temporaries" I mentioned above are really "prvalue expressions". Those are the `std::string("foo")` or `int()` kind of things, but not the `move(s)` and also (for sure) not the `s` kind of things. The `decltype` operator yields a non-reference type for the first kind of "temporaries" I talked about above. For the second kind, `move(s)`, which are xvalues, it will yield an rvalue reference. And for the "non-temporaries", i.e the `s` cases, it will yield an lvalue reference.

So to summarize, I will define three precise macros, and you can choose from them

```
#define IS_LVALUE(...) std::is_lvalue_reference<decltype((__VA_ARGS__))>::value
#define IS_XVALUE(...) std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype((__VA_ARGS__))>::value
#define IS_PRVALUE(...) !std::is_reference<decltype((__VA_ARGS__))>::value
```

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. I'm actually looking for prvalues, as this can have copies elided by wrapping them in lambda's (hence delaying their evaluation) before passing them to functions. Doing this for other things I believe is a waste of time.

Comment: Is there a way to tell the difference between std::move(x) and std::move(X())? (the latter benefiting from delayed evaluation).

Answer (score 5):

### EDIT

I realized that my approach does exactly the same thing as the code you said did not work, only logically inverted:

```
std::is_lvalue_reference<decltype((expr))>::value
```

Could you elaborate as to exactly in what kind of a situation it works against your expectations?

---

You can exploit the reference-collapsing rules like this:

```
std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype((expr))&&>::value
```

If `expr` is an lvalue of some (possibly const) type `T`, `decltype((expr))` will resolve to `T&`, and `T& &&` will collapse back to `T&`.

Otherwise, if `expr` is an xvalue of some type `T`, `decltype((expr))` will be `T&&`, and `T&& &&` will reduce to just `T&&`.

Otherwise, `expr` will be a prvalue of some type `T`, `decltype((expr))` will yield `T`, and thus the whole type will be `T&&`.

Examples:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_rvalue : std::is_rvalue_reference<T&&>
{};

struct x {};
x a; const x b{};

static_assert(is_rvalue<decltype((x()))>::value, "x() is an rvalue");
static_assert(!is_rvalue<decltype((a))>::value, "a is an lvalue");
static_assert(!is_rvalue<decltype((b))>::value, "b is an lvalue");
static_assert(is_rvalue<decltype((std::move(a))>::value, "std::move(a) is an rvalue");
```